# Observable - subscribe two methods

Tags: java, android, rx-java

I have the `Observable` like:

```
  Observable<Integer> dropdownChange =     ReactiveUIObservables.selectionChange(myDropdown)
```

I have now:

```
  LifecycleObservable.bindFragmentLifecycle(lifecycle(), dropdownChange)
    .ObserveOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread))
    .SubscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(this::onDropdownChange);
```

And it's working, now after `DropdownChange` I want to run another method on `selectionChange`. How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `subscribe` for calling multiple methods. E.g.

```
subscribe(myValue -> {
      onDropdownChange(myValue); 
      // call the other method 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If all your subscribers need to receive the same events, you can use a [ConnectableObservable](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Connectable-Observable-Operators). The events will not be emitted until you call .connect().

```
Observable<Integer> dropdownChange = ReactiveUIObservables.selectionChange(myDropdown);
ConnectableObservable<Integer> connectableDropdownChange = dropdownChange.publish();

connectableDropdownChange.subscribe(this::onDropdownChange);
connectableDropdownChange.subscribe(this::doSomething);
connectableDropdownChange.subscribe(this::doSomethingElse);

// start emitting events
connectableDropdownChange.connect();
```